# How to FTP transfer files to /var/www?

Tags: server, ftp, webserver

I'm new to linux and I've set up a web server with Ubuntu Desktop edition so I can practice with the GUI a bit before transitioning to Ubuntu Server.

I've already set up a LAMP stack as well as FTP. Now I just need to know how to transfer my web files to the /var/www folder in Ubuntu. Previously I've worked on Mac OS and there's a central server for all the web files where I can FTP to.

Anyone able to help me understand how do I FTP to the /var/www folder in Ubuntu?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure FTP is the solution you would like to use?  Have you heard of SCP?  SCP is just like FTP in that it is used to transfer files, but it is done over SSH, which *can* make it easier to administer and allows you to more securely transfer files.

If you decide to try SCP, you would want to add your user to the *www-data* group (as I imagine it has +RW access to /var/www/) and then execute the following command:

`scp ~/Projects/site/index.html user@host:/var/www/`

If you're 100% sure you want to use FTP, please let us know which FTP daemon/server you are using to better help you configure it to your purposes.

Comment: I prefer using a GUI transfer window if possible as it is easier to simply drag and drop files for transfer. I'm not quite sur what does FTP daemon mean. I'm using Ubuntu Desktop as the server and have installed FTP on it. On my laptop I'm running Mac OS X Mountain Lion and using a program called Forklift for FTP transfer